# Use "include" for ANY string in a array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a search function that takes input/query text from a search bar. I want it to work for multiple search terms like "javascript react" or with more or less search terms. The input is saved in an array in state ("query") and compares to an object "workitem" and its property "description".

Let say:

```
   workitem.description.includes(this.state.query)
```

where

```
  this.state.query // = ["react", "javacript"]
```

Above will only work for certain situations. I want to see if the array/object includes ANY elements of the state. How to do it?

Comment: you can use indexof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// if needed, do a 
// if (!workitem.description || !this.state.query) {
//     return false;
// }
```

Considering `description` is an array:

```
return workitem.description.some(desc => this.state.query.indexOf(desc) >= 0)
```

Considering `description` is a string:

```
return workitem.description
    .split(' ')
    .some(desc => state.query.indexOf(desc) >= 0);
```

Comment: It seems `description` is a string not an array.

Comment: let me do a version for both

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
workitem.description.split(' ').some(str => this.state.query.includes(str))
```